# making protobuf calls with javascript in the browser

Tags: javascript, grpc

I have used `protoc` to compile a `.proto` file into javascript packages which seems to give me files that serialize requests and responses...

Is there a way I can call a function on a gRPC server with these from a browser? I am not too concerned with using ALL of the benefits of gRPC as I know https://github.com/grpc is working on a full web implementation now.

Is there a way to get it to work while waiting for a full implementation to be released?

Comment: Have you tried [grpc-web](https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web)?

Comment: You can also send Protobufs to a standard REST endpoint by e.g. embedding them in the body of a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

We are in the process of publishing https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web .. For early access, please sign up here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/15iRDHoP-VBenc4hWgKn7bk7IirJLgs0uh88nw1vi_Hc/edit